# Proving non-existence of a right inverse when left inverse is known

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I have matrix 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\ 1& 0 \\ 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}$$  and its left inverse
 $$B=\begin{bmatrix} a&1&0\\ b& 0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$
 I have to prove that there is $A$ has not right inverse.

Even though I know this can be proved that $A$ is not square, the directions say not to use this fact.  Now I thought of doing this by proof by contradiction.  I assume that $A$ has a right inverse.

In my textbook, there is a theorem that says if a matrix has both a left and right inverse, then it has only one left inverse and one right inverse, and they are identical.  Thus, B must be a right inverse.

Thus, we can check if $B$ is a right inverse by doing $AB$.
$$AB=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\ 1& 0 \\ 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a&1&0\\ b& 0&1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\ a& 1&0\\b&0&1 \end{bmatrix}\neq I$$.

Thus $B$ is not a right inverse and this contradicts our assumption that $A$ has a right inverse.

Is this the right method of going about proving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning works, but you don't even need to go that far. Your theorem says that if the matrix has a left and right inverse then it has only **one** left inverse. But clearly any value of $a$ and $b$ correspond to a left inverse, so there are an infinite number of left inverses, which contradicts the proposition that you stated.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $A$ is [surjective iff it has a right inverse](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Surjection_iff_Right_Inverse) (and $A$ is [injective iff it has a left inverse](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Injection_iff_Left_Inverse)).

But $A:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ cannot be surjective by the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).